# Bound in terms of harmonic oscillator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I wonder if the following is true: Let $\alpha >0$ be a positive real number, do we have
$$\Vert H^{\alpha} \psi''\Vert \le \Vert H^{\alpha+1} \psi\Vert,$$
where $H = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x^2$ is the quantum harmonic oscillator or is this false?

It feels natural since $ -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}  \le H$ in the sense of operators.

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|$ the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$-norm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to see that this isn't working is as follows: Take $\psi=\psi_0=e^{-x^2/2}$ as the ground state of $H$, so $H\psi=\psi$. Since $\psi''=(x^2-1)\psi$ is not a multiple of $\psi_0$, we have $\psi''=a\psi_0+\varphi$, with $\varphi\perp\psi_0$, $\varphi\not=0$ and $\|H\varphi\|\ge\lambda \|\varphi\|$ and $\lambda>1$ since $H$ has discrete spectrum.

Thus the inequality fails when $\alpha$ is large.

Comment: Indeed. But, still, there are some true things that can be said, although not so clear as this. When an operator is a sum of two, that don't commute, there is a combinatorial dance to be done to determine the true version of this "obvious" inequality. :)